# GET in POST form

Tags: django, django-views

I would like to redirect the user after he logins to the previous page he was visiting.
What I did does not work.

Error

```
'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'next'
```

template.html

```
{% if request.GET.next %}
<form action="{% url "membres.views.login" %}?next={{ request.GET.next }}" method="post" novalidate class="row">
{% else %}
<form action="{% url "membres.views.login" %}?next=/" method="post" novalidate class="row">
{% endif %}
```

view.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = LoginForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data['username']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if user:
                    if user.is_active:
                        auth_login(request, user)
                        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
                        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
                        request.session['user_username'] = username
                        request.session['user_slug'] = user_profile.slug
                        messages.success(request, "Connexion réussie")

                        return redirect(request.GET.next)
                    else:
                        messages.error(request, "Vous n'êtes plus autorisé à vous connecter")
                else:
                    messages.error(request, "Votre identifiant et/ou mot de passe n'est pas correct")

        else:
            form = LoginForm()

        return render(request, 'membres/login.html', locals())
```

Any idea why it does not work?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.GET` is a dictionary-like object, don't do `request.GET.next`, do: `request.GET["next"]`.

Better yet, consider doing: `request.GET.get('next', '/some_default')` so you won't crash if somehow `?next=` is missing.

Note that this only applies **to your view**. In the template, Django will understand `request.GET.next`

---

Note that you might find it simpler to pass `next` as a `hidden` input in your form (otherwise you should escape the `?next=...` part).

Comment: He uses request.GET.next because that's how the template engine works: with a cascade of attribute, key and so on. Why does it not work this way is the question

Comment: @Alvaro You're mistaken: `request.GET.next` works in the **template**, not in the **view**. Read the part in bold maybe..?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that part of his code. You're right